# Checking for PRESENCE of any Android Notifications

Tags: android, notifications, accessibilityservice

I want to be able to programmatically check if there are any notifications present (preferably only non-permanent notifications) in the status bar. This should include all notifications and not just ones created by my app. I don't need information about the specific notifications or even the total number, I just want to know IF there are notifications being displayed in the status bar currently or not.

I have researched and found that I'm likely going to have to deal with the accessibility service. That's fine, but so far I haven't found a solution to check for current notifications, all solutions so far only show how to detect NEW notifications. I want to be able to query at any instant and check for presence of notifications.

One (ugly) option would be to constantly keep track of all new notifications and clearing of notifications, but I fear this may not be reliable. I want to know if there any simpler or cleaner methods.

Any guidance will be really helpful.

Comment: I doubt that there's a good answer for this.

Comment: Yeah that's what I fear.